# rake aborted! stack level too deep

Tags: ruby, stack-overflow, ruby-1.9.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails 3.0 & Ruby 1.9.2rc: Rake commands return 'already initialized constant' & stack level too deep errors. Any ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183495/rails-3-0-ruby-1-9-2rc-rake-commands-return-already-initialized-constant)

Am using Ruby version 1.9.1 on windows vista. Am getting the rake aborted error for any rake commands am using. This does not happen in all my app folder. Its happening only on a specific app folder.

```
C:\rails_project\stunetwork>rake db:reset
(in C:/rails_project/stunetwork)
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
C:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rak
efile'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: can you made same command with --trace argument ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try placing bundle exec in front of the rake command.

```
bundle exec rake -T
```

Comment: Not sure what the -T is for, but this worked for me. $bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: -T just gives a list of all possible rake commands.

Comment: I'm new to Ruby on Rails,
But i know that in my case bundler got installed as well...
look at [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) for more info

Comment: How do I fix it permanently? So I won't have to type `bundle exec` anymore..

Comment: fyi the full rake list from -T is: `rake about
rake assets:clean
rake assets:precompile
rake db:create
rake db:drop
rake db:fixtures:load
rake db:migrate
rake db:migrate:status
rake db:rollback
rake db:schema:dump
rake db:schema:load
rake db:seed
rake db:setup
rake db:structure:dump
rake db:version
rake doc:app
rake log:clear
rake middleware
rake notes
rake notes:custom
rake rails:template
rake rails:update
rake routes
rake secret
rake stats
rake test
rake test:recent
rake test:single
rake test:uncommitted
rake time:zones:all
rake tmp:clear
rake tmp:create`

Comment: Tried bundle rake db:reset and I got this: Could not find command "rake".

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your gem.
I met this error with gem '1.8.10', and fixed by upgrading to 1.8.16

`gem update --system`

Comment: true this was a bug and was fixed with https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/7d43f1418a048bac277344df962aafd00797230b - available in 1.8.16

Comment: Tried that and got this: Latest version already installed. Done.

Answer (score 2):

I only had this problem with ruby-1.9.2-p180 via rvm.

Switching to ruby-1.9.2-p0 fixed the problem.
try "rvm use 1.9.2-p0"

Comment: I tried this solution, did't work for me. Do you know any other idea?

Comment: it did not worked because it's not related, this bug was fixed in rubygems 1.8.16

Answer (score 0):

The stack of the calls can depend on the gems you install (some gems monkeypatch the rails tasks) which explains why you would encounter this on a specific app and not on others.

On a unix system you could try using the ulimit command to increase your stack size. On the windows side I haven't found a solution yet.

Depending on which release of ruby you use on windows you may want to ask the maintainers how to increase the stack.

For ruby installer you will need to install the mingw compile environment, clone the [github repository](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller) and recompile the ruby you use (not very sexy I admit).

Comment: I liked this, thanks! Unfortunately wasn't enough. I set: "ulimit -s unlimited" then checked "ulimit -a" and stack is unlimited. It still says the same "stack too deep" error. What be be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this exact error message on Ubuntu, and was able to solve it by [downgrading rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523993/how-do-you-downgrade-rubygems) from 1.8.3 to 1.7.1.

Comment: As Rubygems 1.7.1 was released on April 1, 2011, and this question was asked on August 11, 2010, it may have been a different problem, even if the error messages were similar.

Comment: @Andrew yes, that's quite likely. However, since this solution took me a while to work out and solved my problem, I thought it would be a good idea to post it here, even at the risk of confusing people from 2010.

Comment: I am having this issue as well. It seems that version 1.8.10 is incompatible with rake 0.8.7.

Comment: this bug was fixed in rubygems 1.8.16, just update to latest version

Answer (score 0):

There is nice post by Yehuda Katz that explains why without `bundle exec` there can be version conflicts:
http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/

There is also `bundle install --binstubs` command that allows to version-safely run `rake db:reset` like this: `bin/rake db:reset`.