# Unable to run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, dbmigrate

I new to rails,
i've done all steps from this tutorial http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac on my ubuntu 11.04 but i'm unable to run rake db:migrate.

It gives to this output:

```
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant MAJOR
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant MINOR
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant BUILD
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant NUMBERS
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/early_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant EARLY
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:73: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:143: warning: already initialized constant Commands
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:364: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:370: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/home/breedish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
```

How can i fix rake to run my initial migration

I have 1.9.2 ruby, 3.0.10 rails

thx for any help

Comment: quick question...why did you use an install guide for MacOS on your ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this error recently too. Resolved it by placing bundle exec in front of the command.

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

[Here's a previous StackOverflow question with the same error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456304/rake-aborted-stack-level-too-deep)

[And, there's more information about bundle exec here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-dbmigrate-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install an older version of rake.

`gem install rake -v=0.8.7`

You might get a warning message when using rake.

WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.

You can just add "include Rake::DSL" to the Rakefile before the applications load_tasks were called.

I found a post to fix that issue.
[Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199301/global-access-to-rake-dsl-methods-is-deprecated)