# rails3 rake db:migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

Helo,

I am trying to run rake db:migrate for my rails 3 application using mysql2 gem.
But it ended up with below error.
Do you have any idea? 
Thanks

```
WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.7) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant MAJOR
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant MINOR
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant BUILD
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant NUMBERS
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/early_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant EARLY
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:73: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:143: warning: already initialized constant Commands
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:364: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:370: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/Users/Sako/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
```

Comment: What version of the Rails gem are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the error message:

```
 WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x
```

Just fix the mysql version in your gemfile :)

Comment: hi apneadiving, thanks for your suggestion. I have downgraded mysql gem to 0.2.7 , but upon running rake db:migrate it asked me 0.3.7 and recommended me to run bundle install.. back to zero

Comment: What are your rails and arel versions?

Comment: i've added gem 'mysql2', '0.2.7' inside GemFile, and the first 2 lines of warning disappeared, however subsequent error lines are still the same .. :(

Comment: hi apneadiving, i found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456304/rake-aborted-stack-level-too-deep  i.e. by running bundle exed rake db:migrate, the cause is incompatible ruby version..  it is really painful to install mysql in mac (maybe only for me). THANKS apneadiving

Comment: I thought you were using this command already :) consider accepting this answer if it has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

check GemFile and just edit the rails version from 3.0.0 to 3.1.0 and don't care about mysql version, keep it 0.3.7, you don't have to downgrade it