# Problems with Ubuntu Rails install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying my best to get Ruby on Rails installed on Ubuntu 11.04.
I followed the tutorial here: http://stuffingabout.blogspot.com/2011/04/installing-rails-3-on-ubuntu-1104.html

This worked fine until it was installing the documentation for rails-3.0.10 and it had the error:

> Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.10...
>   file 'lib' not found

I checked rails was actually installed however using `rails -v` and saw that rails-3.0.10 was in fact installed.

So, i decided to make a test rails project. I ran into major problems whenever I ran a `rake` command.

Here is the process of my rails project

```
rails new blog
  create  
  create  README
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/mailers
  create  app/models
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  doc
  create  doc/README_FOR_APP
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
  create  log
  create  log/server.log
  create  log/production.log
  create  log/development.log
  create  log/test.log
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/index.html
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  public/images
  create  public/images/rails.png
  create  public/stylesheets
  create  public/stylesheets/.gitkeep
  create  public/javascripts
  create  public/javascripts/application.js
  create  public/javascripts/controls.js
  create  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
  create  public/javascripts/effects.js
  create  public/javascripts/prototype.js
  create  public/javascripts/rails.js
  create  script
  create  script/rails
  create  test
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/functional
  create  test/integration
  create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  test/unit
  create  tmp
  create  tmp/sessions
  create  tmp/sockets
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/pids
  create  vendor/plugins
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
sean@sean-ubuntu:~/university/rails$ cd blog/
sean@sean-ubuntu:~/university/rails/blog$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.10) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.10) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.3) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.14) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.29) 
Using actionpack (3.0.10) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.2) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.2.19) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.10) 
Using arel (2.0.10) 
Using activerecord (3.0.10) 
Using activeresource (3.0.10) 
Using bundler (1.0.18) 
Using rdoc (3.9.3) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.10) 
Using rails (3.0.10) 
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
sean@sean-ubuntu:~/university/rails/blog$ rake db:create
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant MAJOR
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant MINOR
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant BUILD
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant NUMBERS
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/early_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant EARLY
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:73: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:143: warning: already initialized constant Commands
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:364: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:370: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
```

Sorry for the long list of code but it might help solve the problem. Why is rake giving me this error??

Comment: Not sure did you try `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. Shouldn't make a difference though.

Comment: The answer on this page seems to work
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183495/rails-3-0-ruby-1-9-2rc-rake-commands-return-already-initialized-constant-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bundle exec rake db:migrate is what you need.